# How to compare two dates using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to compare 2 dates. one is "current and" and second is "reset date".

```js
    const todayDate = () => {
      const date = new Date();
      date.setDate(date.getDate()); 
  
      const dd = date.getDate();
      const mm = date.getMonth();
      const y = date.getFullYear();
  
      const currentDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;
      return currentDate
    }

    if (resetDate > todayDate) {
      return res.json(`Sorry, you can't change the username right now. Try again at ${resetDate}`)
    }
```

I get the reset date from the database and their "structure" looks like that: "1/1/0000"

So I want to check if the reset date is > than today date but it looks like it doesn't work.
Does anyone have an idea how can I check if the reset date is > that today date?
Like, compare 2 dates.

Comment: 1. `todayDate` is a function, not a value, you're trying to check if `resetDate` is "greater than" the function that returns today's date. You need to *call* a function to get value. 2. The string that the function returns is not naturally sortable. Checking if `"2/1/2020" > "3/1/1999"` would return `false` because `"2" > "3"` is `false`. You need to either convert your database date to a Date object or format it into a sortable format like ISO 8601. 3. `date.setDate(date.getDate())` is useless. It's setting the date to be the same as the same date.

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure Your date format is correct. if it's not working then go for the following steps:

1. You can use moment for this comparison.
2. Get time from date and match them.

According to me go for moment(https://momentjs.com/). it's tested and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with this code:

```js
function dateIsValid( resetDate ) {
  var resetDate = new Date( resetDate );
  if ( resetDate > new Date() ) { // new Date() returns today date
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function checkDate( resetDate ) {
  if ( !dateIsValid( resetDate ) ) {
    return JSON.stringify(`Sorry, you can't change the username right now. Try again at ${resetDate}`);
  } else {
    // do whatever
    return JSON.stringify('Your username changed successfully');
  }
}

// here is an example:
console.log( checkDate('2020/12/1') );
```

Comment: You are not using the date format that @Luc is receiving from the DB `d/m/yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using EU time format **dd.mm.yyyy** so the first thing would be to slice the date strings to be able to create a Date objects.

And then, once having the Date objects, the `getTime()` method can be used to retrieve the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch (1 jan, 1970) to compare both dates.

```js
const dateOne = createDateObj('23/11/2021'),
      dateTwo = createDateObj('22/03/2022');

function createDateObj(date){
  let d = date.slice(0,2),
      m = date.slice(3,5),
      y = date.slice(6,10);

  return new Date(y,m,d)
}

if(dateOne > dateTwo){
  console.log('date one is more recent than date two')
}
else{
  console.log('date two is more recent than date one')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest thing. Since you're already breaking down to yy/mm/dd, then create a new value of:

```
_reset = resetYear*400 + (resetMonth-1)*32 + resetDate

_now = /* ... */
```

and check if `_reset > _now`

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? And use `code formatting` where appropriate. Why multiply the year with 400? Why multiply the month with 32? Why not compare unix timestamps instead?